# How do I search for a specific question whose url I know?

Tags: feature-request, search

I was wondering if there is a feature in the API that I could use to retrieve various features of a question on the Stack Exchange network when I know the actual URL of the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The API allows you to [get question data based on ID](https://api.stackexchange.com/docs/questions-by-ids), so since all forms of question URLs for Stack Exchange sites have an ID in them, you can pull that value out and pass it to the `/questions/{ids}` route.

Likewise, if you don't know the specific site in advance, you can pull out the hostname and [pass that in](https://stackapps.com/questions/3709/how-to-get-the-site-name-from-document-to-pass-to-api) dynamically.

As an example, I parse out similar information in a [userscript I maintain](https://github.com/rchern/StackExchangeScripts/blob/master/SECommentLinkHelper.user.js).